# How to set up a numerical input and not have body disappear in flutter?

Tags: flutter

So, I'm trying to get a numerical input for a price range set up. And yet no matter what I do from looking elsewhere, when I run it, the body is blank. Here's what I'm trying to get it to look like: [price input range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H3TQ.png)

And here's my code for it:

```
Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                color: Color(0xFFffffff),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      '\$',
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: _textFieldController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      'To',
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      '\$',
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: _textFieldController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your Textfield with Expanded widget in following way.

```
 Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _textFieldController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ),
```

But if you want to limit your TextField widget's width then wrap TextField in following way.

```
  Container(
                    width: 50,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _textFieldController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

**Note:** Here you are using same controller for two TextField, which will not give you correct value of textfield, so have to provide different controllers.